# wpf display drawing in an Image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I recently started learning WPF. In my program I need to draw a picture at runtime and display it. It seems that I should use Image class, but how should I paint the picture and display it? Using windows forms I would initialize Graphics and draw in a Bitmap displaying it in a PictureBox. Can I do something simmilar in WPF? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

plenty of examples here in SO:

[Drawing Pixels in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443867/drawing-pixels-in-wpf)

[WPF Canvas - Single Pixel Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916496/wpf-canvas-single-pixel-grid)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx